# Funding with BTC to ETH in mist/ethereum wallet and not receiving Anything

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, shapeshift

I funded my ethereum acocunt with 1 btc.  I entered the "deposit address" into coinbase and it has since been confirmed over 500 times.  It says complete yet i dont see any ether in my account.

It is not synced and is taking multiple days to sync and I unfortunately had to restart so I am back to 1%, but does it have to sync to show the funds were received?
Is this normal?
Should I be worried my ETH is gone?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Contact shapeshift.io support with your transaction ID :)